# Python not sorting as expected

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

I'm trying to sort alphanumerics using python. But I can't get them in the order that I would like.

#### printer.py

```
class Lease:
  def __init__(self, renter=None, property=None, text=None):
    self.renter = renter
    self.property = property
    self.text = text

lease_list = []
lines = open('input.txt', 'r')

for line in lines:
    l, m = line.split(' - ')
    l = re.sub(r"\D", "", l)
    lease_list.append(Lease(m,l, line))
lines.close()

lease_list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.property)
for lease in lease_list:
    print lease.text
```

#### current output

```
#1B - Jackson
#1A - Brown
#100 - Rice
#50 - Smith
#8 - Smith
```

#### desired output

```
#1A - Brown
#1B - Jackson
#8 - Smith
#50 - Smith
#100 - Rice
```

#### input.txt

```
#50 - Smith
#8 - Smith
#100 - Rice
#1B - Jackson
#1A - Brown
```

Comment: what does the input look like? you sort over property but you are printing only text.

Comment: I dont understand how you are sorting to get your desired output... (Ie why is K before A  if you are sorting on names ... or why is 1B before 8 if you are sorting on the numbers)

Comment: Please describe the ordering your want.

Comment: Is your python script really in a file called "printer.rb" ?

Comment: maybe this is supposed to be a ruby script?

Comment: @khelwood Mistype thanks

Comment: @SimoneZandara I've add the input above

Comment: @JoranBeasley The part after `-` doesn't matter I am trying to sort by the numeric value  the line

Comment: `obj.property` is a string, not a number, so it gets sorted lexicographically, not numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the literal in here

```
   l = re.sub(r"\D", "", l)
```

This is what the property list looks like

```
50
8
100
1
1
```

So the sorting is correct. The problem is that neither string sorting nor numerical sorting will work. You have to sort first on the number and then on the literal. This will work but it's inefficient. You might need to create a temporary array with the formatted data and sort on it.

```
for line in lines:
    l, m = line.split(' - ')
    lease_list.append(Lease(m,l, line))

lease_list.sort(key=lambda obj: (int(re.sub(r"\D", "", obj.property)), re.sub(r"[^A-Z]+", "", obj.property))  )
for lease in lease_list:
    print(lease.text)
```

Just an idea for efficiency:

```
for line in lines:
    l, m = line.split(' - ')
    formatted_data.append({'property' : int(re.sub(r"\D", "", l))
        , 'literal' : re.sub(r"[^A-Z]", "", l)
        , 'm': m
        , 'line': line})

formatted_data.sort(key=lambda obj: (obj['property'], obj['literal']))
for lease in formatted_data:
    print(lease['line'])

for line in formatted_data:
    lease_list.append(Lease(line['m'], line['property'], line['line']))
```

Comment: @dabhand That give me "100, 1A, 1B, 50, 8"